# why do js liquid don't render product variable?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have, in product-template.liquid

```
<script src="{{ 'variant.js' | asset_url }}" defer="defer"></script>
```

And variant.js.liquid is this

```
alert('{{product.title}}');
```

But the render of variant.js is

```
alert('')
```

Do I need anymore for rendering?

Comment: I thought that the .liquid files were rendered before delivery but it seems that you have to manually render them in the template itself where you want to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot include a script like that and expect that to be interpreted server side.

Or you do as suggested by Jahanzaib Muneer or you can do like this

```
<script>
    {% render 'variant.js.liquid' %}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, js files are not supposed to run liquid and "js.liquid" files do not work.

It give us error:

> MIME type ('application/x-liquid') is not executable

If you really want to get the liquid variable value in JS then you can use the Shopify Global JS variable.

As per your example:

Add this to your product template:

```
<script>
  Shopify.product_title = '{{ product.title }}';
</script>
```

In your JS file use this:

```
console.log(Shopify.product_title);
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Thanks